# Evaluating line integral on the curve

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have this problem that I *think* I'm doing right, but not getting the correct answer. Could someone point out where I'm screwing up here?

Evaluate
$$ \int_C G(x,y,z) \, ds$$
on the curve indicated by 
$$ x= \frac13 t^3, \quad y=t^2, \quad z=2t, $$
where $t$ is on the closed interval $[0,1]$ for $G(x, y, z) = 4xyz$. Round in the hundredths place.

Following the line integral formula in the text book, I'm getting

$$ \int_0^1 [\frac{8t^6}{3} \sqrt{t^4 + 4t^2 + 4}] \, dt.$$
Exact value is 1.06, which is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
 \int_0^1 \frac83 t^6 \sqrt{t^4 + 4t^2 + 4}] \, dt&=\frac83\int_0^1  t^6 \sqrt{(t^2 + 2)^2}] \, dt \\
&= \frac83 \int_0^1  (t^8  +2t^6)  dt \\
&= \frac83 \left(\frac19 +\frac27 \right)\\
&=\frac{200}{189}
\end{align}$$